# Matlab convert 4x4 into many 2x2 outputs assigned to one variable

Tags: algorithm, matlab

[image]

Could some one please provide a solution to turn this same outcome into one variable and limit the lines of code please. Im having trouble on how to work this algorithm.

Comment: Please do not post images of code, [edit] your question and post [formatted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) text instead

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add code and data as text ([using code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.  See [mcve] on what code is required.

Comment: As you've noticed, hand-copying all those lines of code over and over again to do the exact same thing is cumbersome. More than that: it's detrimental for the execution speed, obfuscates your code and can lead to hard to debug errors. Please see [this answer of mine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/381523/325771) on why this is terrible to do.

Answer (score 2):

Don't create dynamic variable names with numbers as part of the name. These variables will be hard to work with downstream in your code. Instead, you could use multi-dimensional arrays or perhaps cell arrays, which would allow you to use simple indexing downstream. E.g., here is a cell array approach:

```
[m n] = size(test_gray);
m2 = 2*ones(m/2,1);
n2 = 2*ones(n/2,1);
newarray = mat2cell(test_gray,m2,n2)
```

Now you can get at the individual 2x2 matrices with simple indexing into newarray.